# Java Virtual Machine Launcher Error when presents particular piece of code

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea

I have a code that that reads parameters from XML file. In debugger everything works fine, but after I built JAR file and run it - I get the following window

### Java Virtual Machine Launcher

### A Java Exception has occured.

But if I comment this piece of code:

```
else if (settingName.equals("log_level")) {
    String value = element.getAttribute("value");
    if (value.equals("full")) {
        modelLogLevel = EnLogDetails.LOG_FULL;
    } else if (value.equals("apdu")) {
        modelLogLevel = EnLogDetails.LOG_APDU;
    } else if (value.equals("none")) {
        modelLogLevel = EnLogDetails.LOG_NONE;
    } else {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(new String[]{"log_level"});
    }
}
```

and rebuild JAR again - it works fine. How to fix this issue?

Comment: ClassNotFoundException I suppose?

Comment: `throw new InvalidArgumentException(new String[]{"log_level"});` what is the meaning of this? why not `throw new InvalidArgumentException("log_level");`?

Comment: I'm not an expert in exceptions in Java, so typed `InvalidArgumentException`, Idea imported the following namespace: `com.sun.javaws.exceptions`. This class doesn't have a constructor with string parameter. When I changed exception class to `IllegalArgumentException` - issue solved. Thanks for being sent to the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

You've provided exactly none of the relevant information, such as the actual exception or the command line you are using, but clearly you are supplying a log_level argument that doesn't match any of those tests, so you are throwing an IllegalArgumentException which is terminating main() and therefore the launcher. If so it is a complete mystery to me why you need to come to StackOverflow to have your own code explained to you.

Or else the references to EnLogDetails are failing in some way which is shown in the exception which you haven't supplied.